# Excel to have the current date be "tomorrow" at a certain time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to get excel to update the "working date" at 8PM which would allow the date to be tomorrow until 12AM at which point it would remain today until 8PM.

''' =IF(TIME("08:00:00 PM")>=, [TODAY()+1], [TODAY()]) '''

or

''' =IF(NOW()>=TIME(20,0,0), [TODAY()+1], [TODAY()]) '''

Granted neither of these work right now.
Syntax Errors, unsure where.

I bow to intellects far greater and superior than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW` returns a date and time. The date is an integer number. If you substract the integer you het the time.

`IF(NOW()-INT(NOW)>=TIME(20,0,0),TODAY()+1,TODAY())`

Note that it will only update if a (any) change is made within the sheet (or on opening the file).

Comment: So IF(NOW()-INT(NOW())>=TIME(20,0,0),TODAY()+1,TODAY()) Works, However the logical expression it answers with Translates TODAY() as 44636 and TODAY()+1 44637 respectively.  Is there a way for it give the dates instead of those integer values?

Comment: Excel dates are stored as numbers like that. Simply format the result as date and you've got what you want.